# Why is my Open Sans text all clumped up here and how do I avoid it happening?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Using the `letter-spacing` attribute still doesn't seem to make the font render as nicely as it should.

What is the cause of this and how do I resolve it?

The font being used is Open Sans.

[image: Clumpy text]

Comment: What browser? Where are you loading the font from?

Comment: Like Mooseman asked, you really need to include more details in a question like this. Can you paste the CSS that you're applying to that text here please. Along with what browsers you're seeing the issue in. Is it just one or all? Are you using any kind of typekit?

Comment: @Mooseman looks like a book reader - Kindle or the like.

Comment: It's just in Google Chrome.

Comment: I'm not loading in a ttf file or anything like that. I suppose the font is installed on my machine?

Comment: You need to specify what “this” is (the thing that is wrong), show what code you have tried, what browser(s) you tested it in, etc., *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 1):

Never rely on fonts that may or may not be installed (correctly, or, at all) on a client's machine. You can include a copy of Open Sans for free from Google Fonts:

Open Sans is [here](http://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Open+Sans). Make sure you select applicable styles. e.g., bold, etc.